# Propagating crassula leafs and cuttings in Lechuza PON soil

Tags: succulents, propagation

I'm going to propagate my crassula cuttings and leafs.
I did put them into water and there are very little roots appeared though 20 days passed.
I know that the best way to propagate crassula leaf or cutting is to put it directly into soil for succulents.
My current crassula tree (I've got cuttings & leafs from it) is growing in Lechuza PON soil for almost a year and it looks it feels pretty good.

But I still have a question. Can I put my crassula cuttings and leafs directly into such a soil? I'm asking it because it is granular and tough.

Answer (score 2):

A succulent is unlikely to grow roots if it is in water, because it doesn't *need* any roots to absorb water through the stems or leaves.

The way to make a succulent leaf or cutting start to grow roots is to keep it *dry.* Then it will grow some roots trying to *find* water. Just put a few crassula leaves on a piece of paper, leave it somewhere that gets plenty of light and warmth, and wait a few days.

Comment: Can I do the same with cuttings? And what do you think about putting it into Lechuza PON soil (which is granular soil).